# What is the correct way to import a file in typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, import

historically when importing javascript files, you name the file index.js and then import like so

`import something from 'components/path/something'` where the last something is a directory with the `index.js` file in

but with TS I get an error saying: no file or directory when I switch the file name to `index.ts`

2 solutions so far `import something from 'components/path/something/index.ts'`

or

`import something from 'components/path/something/something'`

not a huge fan of either, is there a better approach to this?

Comment: This may or may not help - [Module Resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is no correct way:

Imports are usually relative:

```
import whatever from '../another/folder/'; // will import index
```

Of course you can adapt this behavior in tsconfig.json:

```
{
  ....
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@services/*": ["services/*"],
      "@shared/*": ["shared/*"],
      "@models/*": ["models/*"],
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

Provides you an "absolute project path":

```
import WhateverService from '@services/WhateverService';
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html